# FTP suddenly refuses connection after multiple & sporadic file transfers

Tags: linux, apache, ftp, cpanel, whm

I have an issue that my idiot web host support team cannot solve, so here it is:

When I'm working on a site, and I'm uploading many files here and there (small files, most of them a few dozen lines at most, php and js files mostly, with some png and jpg files), after multiple uploads in a very short timeframe, the FTP chokes on me. It cuts me off with a "refused connection" error from the server end as if I am brute-force attacking the server, or trying to overload it. And then after 30 minutes or so it seems to work again.

I have a dedicated server with inmotion hosting (which I do NOT recommend, but that's another story - I have too many accounts to switch over), so I have access to all logs etc. if you want me to look.

Here's what I have as settings so far:

- I have my own IP on the whitelist in the firewall.
- FTP settings have maximum 2000 connections at a time (Which I am
  nowhere near close to    hitting - most of the accounts I manage
  myself, without client access    allowed)
- Broken Compatibility ON
- Idle time 15 mins
- On regular port 21
- regular FTP (not SFTP)
- access to a sub-domain of a major domain

Anyhow this is very frustrating because I have to pause my web development work in the middle of an update. Restarting FTP on WHM doesn't seem to resolve it right away either - I just have to wait. However when I try to access the website directly through the browser, or use ping/traceroute commands to see if I can reach it, there's no problem - just the FTP is cut off.

Comment: And you're absolutely _stuck_ on using FTP? That's horrible. If your hosting provider doesn't provide SFTP or `rsync` or `git` or something -- _anything_ -- better than FTP, I'd suggest moving.

Comment: creature of habit - I'll just start using SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp` server is configured for such a behavior. If you cannot change its configuration (or switch to another `ftp` server program on the server), you can't avoid that.

For example [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/vsftpd_conf.html) has many such configuration switches.

Going to something else like `scp` or `ssh` should help

(I'm not sure that calling *idiot* your web support team can help you)

Comment: I had no idea this was a standard FTP behaviour. You'd think my web host team would know this stuff. I'm switching to SFTP perhaps.